# JMXBeanWrapper can not access a member of class "JMX" with modifiers "public"

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to use the [JMXWrapper](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JMXWrapper) class/project

For a current project for a set of JMX classes all of them work in peace on either JConsole or VisualVM

For one of them I tried to adapt or work with `JMXWrapper`:

```
public interface MainJmxMBean {

    boolean showIfMainIsRunning();

    void stopMain();

}
```

and

```
@JMXBean(description="Administrates the Main app", sorted=true)
class MainJmx implements MainJmxMBean {

    private boolean isMainRunning;

    MainJmx() {
        isMainRunning =true;
    }


    @Override
    @JMXBeanOperation(name="Show If Main Is Running",
                      description="Shows if the Main app is running or not",
                      sortValue="1")
    public boolean showIfMainIsRunning() {
        return isMainRunning;
    }


    @Override
    @JMXBeanOperation(description="Stops the Main app", sortValue="2")
    public void stopMain() {
        isMainRunning = false;
    }

}
```

**Note:** The class shown above works fine without the annotations. Now was annotated to improve the information and its use in JConsole/VisualVM

And finally

```
private void registerMBeanWithJMXBeanWrapper(ObjectJmxMBean objectJmxMBean) {

    try {
        //System.out.printf("%s %n", objectJmxMBean.toString());
        ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName(objectJmxMBean.getName());
        server.registerMBean(new JMXBeanWrapper(objectJmxMBean.getObject()), objectName);
    }
    catch(MalformedObjectNameException |
          InstanceAlreadyExistsException |
          MBeanRegistrationException |
          NotCompliantMBeanException |
          IntrospectionException e) {
        System.err.printf("[CanonicalName] %s - ERROR: %s %n", e.getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The important part of above is: `new JMXBeanWrapper(objectJmxMBean.getObject())`

Until here I did do all the instructions according with the `JMXBeanWrapper` documentation shared in the link in the top of this post and even from the author's post:

- [Adding descriptions to JMX beans using an annotation wrapper](https://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/)

When I run the Main app, through either JConsole or VisualVM I can see the annotations being applied and working how is expected, therefore until here the goal seems been accomplished.

[image]

[image]

**Problem:** the problem is when I do click to either of them arises:

[image]

The complete error message is:

```
Problem invoking stopMain: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException 
Class com.udojava.jmx.wrapper.JMXBeanWrapper can not access a member of class 
com.manuel.jordan.jmx.admin.MainJmx with modifiers "public"
```

**Observation:** *seems* the error is thrown directly by JConsole or VisualVM, because according with the [JMXBeanWrapper.java](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JMXWrapper/blob/master/src/com/udojava/jmx/wrapper/JMXBeanWrapper.java) source code, there is no the `throw new IllegalAccessException` statement with the part of that message `with modifiers "public"`

**Note & Observation:** according with the project shared on Github, it was tested with JDK 6 and I am using/working with JDK 8.

What could be wrong or missing in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following:

Edit from:

```
@JMXBean(description="Administrates the Main app", sorted=true)
class MainJmx implements MainJmxMBean {

    private boolean isMainRunning;

    MainJmx() {
        isMainRunning =true;
    }
```

To

```
@JMXBean(description="Administrates the Main app", sorted=true)
public class MainJmx implements MainJmxMBean {

    private boolean isMainRunning;

    MainJmx() {
        isMainRunning =true;
    }
```

**Conclusion:** the `JMXWrapper` needs that the class annotated with `@JMXBean` must be `public`.

How you can see the constructor can remain being `package default`